# Error sending complex JSON

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

I am using springmvc with rest, I have 2 project one is of web layer and other one is of rest layer.

Now I have one patient object having set of address and contactinfo, now I am trying to create Json object of patient and sent it over REST request, but here at REST service layer I am unable to get address and contact set.

When I tried to debug the json object on the REST layer & it looks like:

```
{  
   "myHashMap":{  
      "disease":"fever",
      "bloodGroup":"O",
      "contactInfo":{  
         "myArrayList":[  
            {  
               "myHashMap":{  
                  "contactInfoId":1,
                  "fixedLineNo":"fixedline",
                  "mobileNo":"mobile",
                  "faxNo":"faxno",
                  "emailId":"1@msn.com",
                  "organisationId":101,
                  "locationId":800,
                  "createDate":"Apr 2, 2015 2:01:53 PM",
                  "updateDate":"Apr 2, 2015 2:01:53 PM",
                  "updateUserId":"meenakshi",
                  "createUserId":"rahul",
                  "status":true
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "adressess":{  
         "myArrayList":[  
            {  
               "myHashMap":{  
                  "addressId":100,
                  "city":"indore"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**The json object  which I am creating in controller layer  is as:**

```
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    Address address = new Address();

    contactInfo.setContactInfoId(1l);
    contactInfo.setCreateDate(new Date());
    contactInfo.setCreateUserId("rahul");
    contactInfo.setEmailId("1@msn.com");
    contactInfo.setFaxNo("faxno");
    contactInfo.setFixedLineNo("fixedline");
    contactInfo.setLocationId(800l);
    contactInfo.setMobileNo("mobile");
    contactInfo.setOrganisationId(101l);
    contactInfo.setStatus(true);
    contactInfo.setUpdateDate(new Date());
    contactInfo.setUpdateUserId("meenakshi");

    patient.setBloodGroup("O");
    patient.setDisease("fever");

    address.setAddressId(100l);
    address.setCity("indore");

    List<ContactInfo> contactInfosList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    contactInfosList.add(contactInfo);

    List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>();
    addressList.add(address);

    patient.setAdressess(new HashSet<Address>(addressList));
    patient.setContactInfo(new HashSet<ContactInfo>(contactInfosList));

   String patientJsonString = gson.toJson(patient);
   JSONObject patientJsonObj = null;
try {
    patientJsonObj = new JSONObject(patientJsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   return patientJsonObj;
```

The code which is used here at REST layer is as:

```
Patient pat = gson.fromJson(patientJsonDto.toString(), Patient.class);
```

but I am not able to retrieve patient object with address and contact info inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your Patient and ContactInfo class?

Answer (score 0):

Juste use something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PatientResource {
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/rest/patient/{id}", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,  
            headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> producePatient(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        try{
            Patient patient = Patient.findById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Patient >(patient , headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error >>> ",e);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":\""+e.getMessage()+"\"}", headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);     
        }
    }
}
```

insure that you have the library jackson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in your classpath, spring will use it by default for all @ResponseBody and wil do the conversion from/to json for you.

Hope that this will help you